# How can i align all the input fields in one line using bootstrap form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on this form where it should be looking like the image attached.
[image: expected result]

But instead its getting something like this.
[image: output]

here is my code:

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="firstname">FirstName</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="lastname">last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="lastname">identification no</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <button>
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: I have checked. your code is working fine may be at your end some bootstrap link is missing please check and use this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

Comment: i use this link <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hi, actually all the link been added correctly. but im not quite sure how arrange the elements inside the form so that the output will be something like the picture attached [first picture]

Comment: I have added ans. for you.   just need add row class instead of form-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that a parent component has the text-center class: `class="text-center"`

Therefore, you should add the `text-start` class to your form in order to achieve your desired alignment.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class="text-center">
<form class="text-start">
  <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label for="firstname" class="form-label">FirstName</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label for="lastname" class="form-label">last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label for="lastname" class="form-label">id no</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <button>
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label for="inputAddress">email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks ya. yes you are correct. need some modification at the parent css there.

Comment: If you've found this answer to be correct, please select it as the correct answer so that others may benefit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to do the same

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Search Profile - Personal</h2>
  <hr>
  <form>
  <div Class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="firstname">FirstName</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="lastname">last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="lastname">identification no</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="font-size:32px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
  </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="usr">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
    </div>
   </div>
  <hr>
    
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```